# Evaluate a function one time and store the result in python

Tags: python, static-methods, evaluation-strategy

I wrote a static method in python which takes time to compute but I want it to compute just one time and after that return the computed value.
What should I do ?
here is a sample code :

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def compute_result():
         #some time taking process 

Foo.compute_result() # this may take some time to compute but store results
Foo.compute_result() # this method call just return the computed result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def evaluate_result():
    print 'evaluate_result'
    return 1

class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def compute_result():
        if not hasattr(Foo, '__compute_result'):
            Foo.__compute_result = evaluate_result()
        return Foo.__compute_result 

Foo.compute_result()
Foo.compute_result()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is called `memoizing`. 
There are several ways to do it with decorators, one of them is using [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) (Python 3) or some [short handwritten code](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php) if you only care for hashable types (also for Python 2).

You can annotate multiple decorators for one method.

```
@a
@b
def f():
   pass
```